# Wrapper Classes java

Tags: java

I'm trying to initialize a 2D arraylist where each col/row has a wrapper object.

```
private WrapperBoard[][] board;


public Board() {;
    for(int row = 0; row <= dime; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col <= dime; col++) {
            board[row][col] = new WrapperBoard();
        }
    }
```

Is what I do to initialize a 2d Arraylist where each object is a wrapperBoard. WrapperBoard is a stack object.

```
I'm recieving the error java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: There's no "stack object" in Java that you're used to.  You need to `new` the Array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few mistakes in your code:

1. you didn't initialize your array first if you want to place something in it. By default non-private fields of class are initialized with `null` that is why you are seeing NPE (you are trying to invoke `[row][col]` on null), so use

   ```
   private WrapperBoard[][] board = new WrapperBoard[dime][dime];
   ```
2. indexes in arrays start from `0` and have max value of `dim - 1` so you should continue iterating while `row < dime`, not `row <= dime` (same about `col`)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't initialize your `board` variable, as there are no "stack objects" in Java as there are in C++.

You must initialize `board` by doing something like

```
private WrapperBoard[][] board = new WrapperBoard[20][20];
```

that will create room for instantiating other objects as you do in your loop.